# Binding to dependencyproperty in user control and calling CanExecute on nested property change

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

I have created a user control that essentially contains a bunch of comboboxes, called SearchParamsControl. The SearchParamsControl contains all the UI elements required to set everything in a SearchParams class:

My SearchParamsControl:

```
    /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for SearchParamsControl.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class SearchParamsControl : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SearchParamsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Radius entries bound to combobox
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<double, string> RadiusEntries
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = new Dictionary<double, string>()
    {
        {0, "This area only" },
        { 0.25, "Within 1/4 mile" },
        { 0.5, "Within 1/2 mile" },
        { 1, "Within 1 mile" },
        { 3, "Within 3 miles" },
        { 5, "Within 5 miles" },
        { 10, "Within 10 miles" },
        { 15, "Within 15 miles" },
        { 20, "Within 20 miles" },
        { 30, "Within 30 miles" },
        { 40, "Within 40 miles" }
    };

    public Dictionary<PropertyTypeEnum, string> PropertyTypes => PropertyTypeDictionary;

    /// <summary>
    /// Prices bound to combo box
    /// </summary>
    public List<int> Prices
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = new List<int>()
    {
        0,
        50000,
        60000,
        70000,
        80000,
        90000,
        100000,
        110000,
        120000,
        125000,
        130000,
        150000,
        200000,
        250000,
        300000,
        325000,
        375000,
        400000,
        425000,
        450000,
        475000,
        500000,
        550000,
        600000,
        650000,
        700000,
        800000,
        900000,
        1000000,
        1250000,
        1500000,
        1750000,
        2000000,
        2500000,
        3000000,
        4000000,
        5000000,
        7500000,
        10000000,
        15000000,
        20000000
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Bedrooms bound to combobox
    /// </summary>
    public List<int> Bedrooms
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = new List<int>()
    {
        0,
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
    };

    public StringTrieSet SearchString
    {
        get
        {
            return RightMoveCodes.RegionTree;
        }
    }

    public double Radius
    {
        get => SearchParams.Radius;
        set
        {
            if (SearchParams.Radius != value)
            {
                SearchParams.Radius = value;
                OnSearchParamsChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public int MinBedrooms
    {
        get { return SearchParams.MinBedrooms; }
        set
        {
            if (SearchParams.MinBedrooms != value)
            {
                SearchParams.MinBedrooms = value;
                OnSearchParamsChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public int MaxBedrooms
    {
        get { return SearchParams.MaxBedrooms; }
        set 
        { 
            if (SearchParams.MaxBedrooms != value)
            {
                SearchParams.MaxBedrooms = value;
                OnSearchParamsChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public int MinPrice
    {
        get { return SearchParams.MinPrice; }
        set 
        { 
            if (SearchParams.MinPrice != value) 
            {
                SearchParams.MinPrice = value;
                OnSearchParamsChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public int MaxPrice
    {
        get { return SearchParams.MaxPrice; }
        set
        {
            if (SearchParams.MaxPrice != value)
            {
                SearchParams.MaxPrice = value;
                OnSearchParamsChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public SortType SortType
    {
        get { return SearchParams.Sort; }
        set
        {
            if (SearchParams.Sort != value)
            {
                SearchParams.Sort = value;
                OnSearchParamsChanged();
            }
        }
    }



    public SearchParams SearchParams
    {
        get
        {
            SearchParams searchParams = (SearchParams)GetValue(SearchParamsProperty);
            return searchParams;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SearchParamsProperty, value);
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MySelectedItem.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchParamsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SearchParams", typeof(SearchParams), typeof(SearchParamsControl), new PropertyMetadata(new SearchParams(), OnSearchParamsPropertyChanged));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private static void OnSearchParamsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchParamsControl c = d as SearchParamsControl;

        if (c != null)
        {
            c.OnSearchParamsChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnSearchParamsChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchParams));
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And the xml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RightMoveApp.UserControls.SearchParamsControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RightMoveApp.UserControls"
         xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
         xmlns:StyleAlias="clr-namespace:RightMove;assembly=RightMove"
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:RightMoveApp.ViewModel"
         xmlns:dataTypes="clr-namespace:RightMove.DataTypes;assembly=RightMove" 
         xmlns:valueconverters="clr-namespace:RightMoveApp.UserControls.ValueConverters"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
         x:Name="uc">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:SearchParamsControlViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="dataTypes:SortType"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <valueconverters:PropertyTypeConverter x:Key="PropertyTypeConverter" x:Shared="False"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
    </Style> 
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Search area"/>

    <local:AutoCompleteComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=SearchString}" 
                                   SelectedValue="{Binding Path=RegionLocation, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Search radius"/>
    <ComboBox Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxTemplate1}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="comboSearchRadius" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=RadiusEntries}" 
              SelectedValuePath="Key" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=Radius, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Content="Price range (£)"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="comboMinPrice" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=Prices}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=MinPrice, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="to"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Name="comboMaxPrice"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=Prices}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=MaxPrice}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Content="No. of bedrooms"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="comboMinBedrooms" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=Bedrooms}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=MinBedrooms, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Name="comboMaxBedrooms" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=Bedrooms}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=MaxBedrooms, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="to"/>
    </Grid>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Content="Sort Type"/>

    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Name="comboSort" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=SortType, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

I want to bind to the SearchParams dependency property in my MainWindow, which contains the SearchParamsControl:

```
<GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Header="Search Params" Panel.ZIndex="10">
    <controls:SearchParamsControl x:Name="searchControl"
                                SearchParams="{Binding Path=SearchParams, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsSearching, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToReverseConverter}}">

    </controls:SearchParamsControl>
</GroupBox>
<Button x:Name="btnSearch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
        Content="Search" 
        IsDefault="True"
        Command="{Binding SearchAsyncCommand}"/>
```

This binding works fine. But, as you can see, I've got a Button in my MainWindow, which is hooked up to a command. I want to know when a property in SearchParams has changed, so that I can called something like SearchCommandAsync.RaiseCanExecuteChanged() so that I can update the state of the Search button. How can I handle this?

Note that I don't want to use the following commented out code (from my Command class), which I think does work, but rather I want to be able to notify that the SearchParams has a changed property and therefore we need to call CanExecute again:

```
        //public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    //{
    //  add
    //  {
    //      CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
    //  }
    //  remove
    //  {
    //      CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    //  }
    //}

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        //CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
```

Also I don't want to modify SearchParams with a PropertyChanged event handler (imagine it is a closed off class library and I can't modify it).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your setup correctly, the `SearchParams` property of the `SearchParamsControl` on the view should set the data-bound `SearchParams` source property of the view model whenever the control property changes.

You can then raise the `CanExecuteChanged` method of the command in the setter of the `SearchParams` source property.

Comment: That's the thing, the SearchParams source property (if you mean the SearchParams in the MainWindowViewModel of my MainWindow) setter is never executed, most likely because it's the SearchParams.Radius, say, that is changed. However, if I force CanExecute to true, I can check my SearchParams of the MainViewModel in the debugger and confirm that the Radius property of SearchParams has correctly updated, but the SearchParams setter breakpoint is never hit. I even tried putting SearchParams=SearchParams in the setting of Radius in the UserControl to try and force callin the setter in MainViewModel

Comment: So the binding doesn't work? By the way, you should remove the `<UserControl.DataContext>` element from the control. A control should inherit its `DataContext` from the parent element.

Comment: My apologies, I have removed that (I've removed the SearchControlViewModel completely). The binding does work, the modified properties of SearchParams are correct in the MainWindowViewModel. When I put a breakpoint in my ExecuteSearch method, I debug the SearchParams and my changes are shown correctly. But SearchParams itself has not changed, so I guess that's why the setter isn't called - but I need it to be called so I can raise CanExecuteChanged

Comment: So how does the control tell the view model that it has changed?

Comment: And that's where my problem lies. How do I go about that?

FYI, just tried putting in the setter of Radius, SearchParams = new SearchParams(SearchParams) (i.e. making new instance of it) and now my SearchParams setter in MainWindowViewModel is called (and I can raise CanExecuteChanged there). This definitely seems a hacky approach, there must a better way.

Comment: The view model should raise an event or set a property or do something to tell the outside world that it has changed.

Comment: Ok cool, thank you. I thought there might be a way to notify that SearchParams has changed through Binding without having to introduce a new event for this purpose.